# How to know that user clicks on the same element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a quiz. It has two questions with four answers each.
I want to hide the submit button until user answers all question.

My code:

```
var answered = 0;
function checkAllAns(){
  ++answered;
  if (answered >= 10)
  {
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

It works only when user answers one time each question, but what if user makes a mistake? Say user answers the same question for 10 times, the submit button appear although all question haven't been answered yet.

I replace it with this:

```
function checkAllAns(index){

  var checkedIndex = [];

  if ( ansAll[index] == false){
    ansAll[index] = true;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < ansAll.length; ++i) {
    if (ansAll[i] == true){
      var checked = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < checkedIndex.length; ++j){
        if ( checkedIndex[j] == ansAll[i] ){
          checked = 1;
        }
        else{
          checkedIndex.push( ansAll[i] );
        }
      }
      if (checked == 0){
        ++answered;
      }
    }
  }

  if (answered >= 10){
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

It does not work (if it is working I won't answer it here...)

What is wrong with my code? If you've find another way to accomplish this, you can suggest me.

Thanks,

My complete code is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjYWWx

Comment: Count the answers instesad of using a counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have the right idea, but you're working too hard, you can just use one array and iterate through that (unless you're worried about a timing attack) like so:

```
function checkAllAns(index)
{
 ansAll[index] = true;

 for (i = 0; i < ansAll.length; ++i)
 {
  if (ansAll[i] != true)
  {
    break;
  }
  if (i == ansAll.length-1)
  {
   document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
   document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.opacity = "1";
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/soyn0xag/6/

Instead of using complex nesting of iterations and loops, use JQuery.

This checks whether the key has left the text area (aka complete)

```
 $("input[type='text'], textarea").on("keyup", function(){
        if($(this).val() != "" && $("textarea").val() != "" && $("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true){
            $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

This check whether the check box has been selected or changed.

```
$("input[name='category']").on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() != "" && $("textarea").val() != "" && $("input[name='category']").is(":checked") == true){
        $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

This checks if the element is checked, when everything is check change the submit to show. This is just a snippet, you will need to expand.

Comment: Nice try, but I can't use jQuery

Comment: Ah no problem, @HBP provides the best answer in this case, good luck solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to go for simpler code and try to integrate it in a single solution. Something like this (untested):

```
function answered(){
  return document.querySelectAll('.question.answered').length;
  }

var answers = document.querySelectAll('.question .answer');
for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
  answers[i].onclick = function(e){

    // This should be the question
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('answered');

    // Check how many questions are answered
    if (answered() > 10) {
      // DO SOMETHING
      }
    }
  }
```

Not tested, but in this way it's much easier. If you also used jQuery or a similar library, it would be much much more easy (as Bradley Wilson's answer point out).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method. Keep an array `answered` and add the question index to it unless that question has already been answered. Whene the array length is 10 then all questions have been answered

```
var answered = [];
function checkAllAns (index) {
   if (answered.indexOf (index) >= 0)
      answered.push (index);

   if (answered.length == 10)
   {
      document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.display = "inline-block";
      document.getElementById("stop-btn").style.opacity = "1";
   }
}
```

Comment: could you add a snippet or put it on jsbin? It's not working for me